# Why does Map#put specify @throws ClassCastException?

Tags: java, generics, javac

Consider the specification for the [`put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase//8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) method of the [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase//8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface.

It says:

```
@throws ClassCastException if the class of the specified key or value 
        prevents it from being stored in this map
```

`Map` is a generic interface with two *type parameters*: `K` and `V` for key objects and value objects respectively. The `put` method signature is:

```
V put(K key, V value);
```

Under what conditions might a call to this method cause a `ClassCastException` at runtime?

I reckon that if there is some mixing of generic and raw types, then while ignoring the compiler warnings this may happen. So, after rereading Effective Java 2, I modeled the following after the `unsafeAdd` example (Item #23, pp. 112):

```
public class MapClassCastException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<>();
        unsafePut(m);
        System.out.println(m.get(1));
    }

    private static void unsafePut(Map m) { // beware: Raw Type
        m.put("blow", "up");
        m.put(new int[]{2, 4}, "xxx");
    }
}
```

But this code does *not* fail at runtime with `ClassCastException`, instead it prints `null`. (Of course, I am ignoring the compiler warnings only to understand it well).

Can someone demonstrate how `Map#put` might throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime? (I tried this with JDK 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 and they produced identical results).

Comment: Try it with `TreeMap`.

Comment: Ah, cool. Thanks @chrylis. I forgot about this useful `Map` implementation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` is an interface, which essentially defines a contract for all implementations of that interface. The documentation for `Map.put` is telling you that it's possible for this method to throw a `ClassCastException`. That doesn't *require* all implementations to throw it.

If you look at the [documentation for `HashMap.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-), you'll notice that it doesn't mention `ClassCastException` at all. As mentioned in the comments, [`TreeMap.put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put-K-V-) does throw a `ClassCastException` because it needs to be able to accurately compare the keys.

If you wanted to implement your own `java.util.Map`, you could then throw `ClassCastException` if you wanted to restrict the type of a key or value, even though the generics on the interface cannot enforce that if you happen to be using a raw `Map` type.

I think this is just the implementors of the Collections API saying to be careful.